# Merging deployment of a mix of project types in .NET

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, deployment, msbuild

I am using VS 2008 / .NET 3.5
I have the following mix of projects that makes up our product:

- A number of backend c# class libraries
- 5 windows services
- 4 Web application projects

I have an MSBUILD proj.xml that lists all the .sln files for each of the above in the correct order and I can build everything in one hit. However when it comes to deployment, I currently publish each web application from VS2008 and then have to manually install each service. In addition there are some configuration files and other bits that I need to copy to the server every time which is a pain.

Is there a way to merge all the above deployment operations into a single project which would automate the deployment process?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at WebDeploy. Although we use it from within TFS, it will do what you need from a batch file.

http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy

Comment: I have had a look at WebDeploy. It doesn't seem to handle windows services for example. Also part of my deployment involves copying files to a destination